# Technique for unifying solutions

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose for some trigonometric equation we have the result as

\begin{equation}2n\pi + \frac{3\pi}{4}\\2n\pi + \frac{7\pi}{4}\end{equation}

I need to unify these so that I can have the result as

$$n\pi + \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Basically I am looking for an algorithm/technique that can unify these results (like the one stated).

More specifically, union of the terms (if exists).

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: factor out $\pi$ from both of your solutions, and look at what's left.

In your first solution, what's left will be $(2n) + \frac{3}{4}$.  In the other, it'll be $(2n+1) + \frac{3}{4}$.

So in one solution you're taking an arbitrary even integer and adding $\frac{3}{4}$, and in the other you're taking an arbitrary odd integer and adding $\frac{3}{4}$.

Can you see how to "unify" these solutions?